# How do I create an Azure Dev Ops release to publish to another organisations tenant

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have created a web application as a private developer for a friends company.  All the code lives within my personal Azure Dev Ops portal and at present has a pipeline configured to build and a release configured to release to a web application within my Azure tenant.

How can I now create a new release pipeline so that the code will be published to the a web application within the companies official Azure tenant?

We have created an Azure subscription and a web application using my friends company office 365 account but I somehow need to grant access or authorise my personal Azure Devops portal to publish.

Comment: Have you use that Azure subscription to create the service connection to publish the your Web App?

Comment: Thanks @Leo Liu-MSFT for responding.  I have discovered there are many ways to achieve this and documented one as my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching and playing it would seem there are many many ways to do this.  In the end I went down the route of adding my friends work account to my Azure DevOps project so that they could create a service connection by authorising with their Office 365 account.

Once done I gained access to the subscription when creating the release.